# failed to start postfix.service: Unit not found

Tags: centos, postfix

I just got my own VPS with CentOS 7, and I'm trying to install GitLab on it. I'm following the instructions listed [here](https://about.gitlab.com/install/#centos-7). My problem is the command `systemctl start postfix`. I did the `yum install postfix`, and this is what resulted:

[image]

Then when I run the start command, I get the following error:

> failed to start postfix.service: Unit not found

I've tried to Google the error, but all the results I've found were other issues. I'm new to this. Am I missing something really silly?

Answer (score 1):

Your cPanel server has `exim` installed in a way that prevents you from installing `postfix`.

It appears that cPanel does not support `postfix` from what I found searching just now.  You would need to [configure your `gitlab` instance to use the SMTP server running on localhost](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html) as it seems `gitlab` is incompatible with the `sendmail` that `exim` provides.